# how can I use two characters that are in the same column to limit my SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql

i need to output all the movies that both "Johnny Depp" and "Helena Bonham Carter" starred. I think my problem is that I dont no what to putt inside of the WHERE

```
SELECT title
FROM movies JOIN
     stars
     ON movies.id = stars.movie_id JOIN
     people ON stars.person_id = people.id
WHERE
```

this is what I got so far...

Comment: Your `WHERE` is in the right place.  Now add the conditions.

Comment: `WHERE person_name = 'Johnny Depp' OR  person_name='Sylvester Stalone'`.    another option is to write   `WHERE person_name in('Johnny Depp','Silvester Stalone','Roger Moore')`

Comment: Do you want the movies where *either one* of them starred or where *both* of them starred?  The comments and answers so far are of the *either one* variety.

Comment: I need them both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend moving the where clause into a query from one of the tables as it will be more efficient. Suppose your `people` table has a field called `name` then you could do a subquery like so:

```
SELECT stars.movie_id, people.name
FROM stars
JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name="Johnny Depp") AS people
ON people.id = stars.people_id
```

This gives all Johnny Depp movies, a similar query gives all Helena Bonham Carter movies. Now you can intersect the two queries:

```
SELECT stars.movie_id, people.name
FROM stars
JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name="Johnny Depp") AS people
ON people.id = stars.people_id
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT stars.movie_id, people.name
                   FROM stars
                   JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name="Helena Bonham Carter") AS people
                   ON people.id = stars.people_id)
```

This gives all movies starring both. Now intersect this with your original query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        title
FROM    movies 
JOIN    stars   ON stars.movie_id   =   movies.id
JOIN    people  ON people.id        =   stars.person_id

WHERE   starred_name IN ('Johnny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Carter')

-- i used "starred_name", becuase you never specified the name of the field.
```

Comment: thank you but i need to find the movies were both are atarring

Comment: table and field where the starred names are stored?

Answer (score 0):

my final cod was:

```
SELECT title
FROM people
JOIN stars ON people.id = stars.person_id
JOIN movies ON stars.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id
                   FROM stars
                   JOIN people ON stars.person_id = people.id
                   WHERE name = "Helena Bonham Carter") and name = "Johnny Depp"
```